# Trouble with \b escape sequence in fprintf statement..?

Tags: c, file, formatting, printf

I am trying to write a program which reads a student number (7-digit string) from a file, replaces the first 3 digits with x's, and prints the result into a new file. I can accomplish what I'm trying to do using a printf statement (printing to the screen), but when using fprintf the result in the new file isn't what i want. Here is the relevant line of code:

```
studentno=1234567
fprintf(fp2, "%s\b\b\b\b\b\b\bxxx\t", studentno);
```

in a `printf` statement, the result is xxx4567, as intended. In an `fprintf` statement, however, when i open the new file it displays 1234567xxx. I'm really not sure why, as other escape sequences such as `'\n'` or `'\t'` seem to work the same in `fprintf` statements as they do in `printf` statements. If anybody could point me in the right direction as to why this is occurring, that would be great.

Comment: How about: `fprintf(fp2, "xxx%d", studentno % 10000);`

Answer (score 0):

You are using it on a a `FILE` type.
If it is a file it will be upto the text editor to do what it wants. if it really is a terminal on the other end you would need to check if it handles those escape characters correctly.

it might even be that it is not allowed to use some escape characters with `printf` family of functions but I am not sure. It is easier if you can avoid them all together in my opinion.

Anyway I would recommended just rewriting the the printf or fprintf statement to do this:

```
fprintf(fp2, "xxx%s", studentno + 3);
```

this will write xxx and then start writing the chars from studentno from the 4th offset. Easier and will work for sure!

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by "when i open the new file". do you open it with an editor? cat? i suspect that  vi newfile may display different than cat newfile. because different software (canonical stdout vs your text editor) may display \b differently or not at all.

in any case, if you are trying to hide the first 3 digits of studentno on the screen, using backspaces is a bad way to go. unreliable and vulnerable. a hacker can easily get the full number by redirecting the output to file and there is no way to prevent it. i agree with rowan.G answer.

Answer (score -1):

You´re mixing up format codes for printf/fprintf and terminal codes, which instruct the terminal to do something.

The allowable format codes for f/printf are listed here and you´ll notice \b isn´t one of them:

[printf format codes references](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

What´s happening is that when you display the string you´re creating on your terminal, the terminal is applying the \b to backspace and effectively display the string as you want, but when you print it to file, it has no effect. There are a number of ways to do what you want, but I would suggest simply reading the student number in from file as a string, and manipulating it in an array.